# VBA Named Range

Tags: vba, named-ranges

I have a code below where i try change the range i reference to a dynamic range. I'm referencing it somehow wrong. Any ideas how to fix this? Basically `Workrange` reference is fine if i go `Workrange.Select`, but it doesn't work in the Intersect context.

```
Set StartCell = Range("A5")
Set StartSheet = Worksheets("Data")

With Worksheets("Data").Range("A4:BZ4")
    Set LastColumn = .Find("Comment", LookIn:=xlValues)
End With

Set Workrange = StartSheet.Range(StartCell, StartSheet.Cells(5000, LastColumn.Column))

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Workrange")) Is Nothing Then ' --> This does NOT work

'If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A5:AC5000")) Is Nothing Then --> THIS WORKS.
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Cells(Target.Row, LastColumn.Column + 1).Value = Environ("username")
Cells(Target.Row, LastColumn.Column + 2).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy_hh.mm.ss")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `If Not Intersect(Target, Workrange) Is Nothing Then`

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

`If Not Intersect(Target, Workrange) Is Nothing Then`

When using `Range("Workrange")` it is looking for a Range, in the Workbook which has been called "Workrange" (Formulas-> Name Manager).

Comment: Actually now the code doesnt seem to react to a change in the cells.

Comment: @Carlsberg789 You're using some unqualified references. It is difficult to say, where the problem is. Try with adjusting these lines: `Set StartCell = Worksheets("Data").Range("A5")`, `StartSheet.Cells(Target.Row, LastColumn.Column + 1).Value = Environ("username")` And `StartSheet.Cells(Target.Row, LastColumn.Column + 2).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy_hh.mm.ss")`